# ASP.NET Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string with Dynamic Textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, textbox

I am getting column type from database and changes the textbox attribute accordingly, for example, if i have a date column to input value , i would add attribute with

```
 Text4.Attributes["Type"] = dataTypeList[3].ToString();
```

which will change the textbox to (ex. input type="date") however, when i want to get the date value ,  "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string with Dynamic Textbox" Occurs , because i am getting it with

```
Text4.Value.ToString()
```

any clue on how i should do it? To get textbox from date dynamically not by using the .selectedDate attribute? As i would not know what input type the textbox will be. Any help is much appreciated , Thanks

Comment: Dynamic textbox means you are creating control at run time and then doing these things or you have a textbox already?

Comment: I have a textbox already but the type will change accordingly , i want to get the data from textbox too and post it to sql

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation I have assumed certain things and tried to visualize your scenario and came across following solution

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicApp.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">
        <div id="textBoxHolder" runat="server"></div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" Text="Show" runat="server" OnClick="btnShow_Click" /><br />
        <asp:Literal ID="litShow" Text="" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DynamicApp
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        // data source
        List<string> dataTypeList = new List<string> { "text", "date", "number" };

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            // creating dynamic textboxes

            var textBoxHolder = (HtmlGenericControl)mainForm.FindControl("textBoxHolder");
            var index = 1;

            foreach (var item in dataTypeList)
            {
                var textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.ID = "txtBox" + (index++);
                textBox.Attributes["type"] = item;

                textBoxHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);
            }
        }

        protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // getting textbox values

            var textBoxHolder = (HtmlGenericControl)mainForm.FindControl("textBoxHolder");

            for (int index = 1; index <= dataTypeList.Count; index++)
            {
                var textBox = (TextBox)textBoxHolder.FindControl("txtBox" + (index));
                litShow.Text += textBox.Text + "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The aspx file is straight forward I have took one button and a literal; also a textBoxHolder which will hold my dynamic textboxes

In the code behind aspx.cs I have made a dummy data source "dataTypeList" with 3 different types then on the page load I am creating and adding dynamic textboxes to the page. Next on btnShow click I am just fetching values from these dynamic textboxes and displaying the text in literal

Sorry if my assumptions are not as per your scenario.

Hope it helps

Comment: That is how i do it but for the date type if it is on the text type when i get value and want to post it to sql, error will pop out , thanks for helping